# Deleting MSWord footers in VSTO

Tags: vba, ms-word, vsto

The following code in Ms Word 2013 VSTO solution triggers COMException (0x800A1710): Cannot edit Range.

```
Section firstSection = document.Sections[1];
foreach(HeaderFooter footer in firstSection.Footers)
{
    if (footer.Exists)
    {
        footer.Range.Delete();
    }
}
```

The same code written as VBA macro executes successfully without any error.

```
Public Sub Test()

Dim section as Section
Set section = ActiveDocument.Sections(1)

Dim footer as HeaderFooter

For Each footer In section.Footers
    If footer.Exists Then
        footer.Range.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestion on why the code behaves differently in VBA macro vs VSTO solution

Comment: Which line of code triggers the error, the Delete action? As a test: are you able to write anything to footer.Range.Text or does that also give you an error? How do you instantiate `document`? And is this a document-level customization or an add-in?

Comment: The error is triggered on footer.Range.Delete() call. I also tried to get the range's paragraphs collection and to remove them one by one; that failed the same way. No, I haven't tried to write to the footer range. The 'document' object is obtained earlier via Application.ActiveDocument property. And this is an Add-in not document level customization. And thanks for the reply.

Comment: What I really needed was to copy headers footers from one section to another. So instead of deleting the H and F I ended up with the code that does copy and paste. Seems to work.